# Qt 5.5 how to rotate polygon around position

Tags: c++, qt5.5

I have a polygon:

```
    QPolygon plyNeedle;
    plyNeedle << QPoint(ptOrigin.x() - intNeedleHalfWidth, ptOrigin.y())
              << QPoint(ptOrigin.x(), ptOrigin.y() + intNeedleHalfWidth)
              << QPoint(ptOrigin.x() + intRadius - intNeedleHalfWidth, ptOrigin.y())
              << QPoint(ptOrigin.x(), ptOrigin.y() - intNeedleHalfWidth);
```

ptOrigin is of type QPoint and defines the rotate point.  intNeedleHalfWidth is an integer and has a value of 4.  intRadius is an integer and defines the length of the needle.

I want to rotate the polygon around the 2nd index of the polygon, but how?

(Edit)...
On trying Answer suggested by Anton Savin, before and transformation:

```
    ptOrigin (40, 250)
    plyNeedle (36,250),(40,254),(287,250),(40,246)
```

After performing:

```
    plyNeedle = QTransform().translate(-ptOrigin.x(), -ptOrigin.y())
                            .rotate(45)
                            .translate(ptOrigin.x(), ptOrigin.y())
                            .map(plyNeedle);
```

plyNeedle is then added to the QPainter:

```
    QBrush brshArrow;
    brshArrow.setColor(mcpszARGBneedle);
    brshArrow.setStyle(Qt::SolidPattern);
    objOffscrPainter.setPen(mcpszARGBneedle);
    QPainterPath path;
    path.addPolygon(plyNeedle);
    objOffscrPainter.drawPolygon(plyNeedle);
    objOffscrPainter.fillPath(path, brshArrow);
```

Nothing is shown, on investigating plyNeedle contains:

```
    plyNeedle (-340,157),(-340,163),(-162,335),(-334,157)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to "Anton Savin", who got me on the right track, after some playing around the actual solution was:

```
    plyNeedle << QPoint(ptOrigin.x() - intNeedleHalfWidth, ptOrigin.y())
              << QPoint(ptOrigin.x(), ptOrigin.y() + intNeedleHalfWidth)
              << QPoint(ptOrigin.x() + intRadius - intNeedleHalfWidth, ptOrigin.y())
              << QPoint(ptOrigin.x(), ptOrigin.y() - intNeedleHalfWidth);
    plyNeedle = QTransform().translate(ptOrigin.x(), ptOrigin.y())
                            .rotate(-mfltElevation)
                            .translate(-ptOrigin.x(), -ptOrigin.y())
                            .map(plyNeedle);
```

This now works perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Something like this:

```
QPoint origin = ...;
plyNeedle = QTransform()
   .translate(-origin.x, -origin.y)
   .rotate(angle)
   .translate(origin.x, origin.y)
   .map(plyNeedle);
```

Comment: Not sure what happened, but the needle disappeared completely, on inspection with debugger I can see the X co-ordinates are massively negative...I'll edit the original post to include the results.